# Is HookConsumerWidget still a part of hooks_riverpod.dart?

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-hooks

I am working on building some of the example hooks_riverpod applications and I get an error that the HookConsumerWidget is not a dart class.  Is this still a valid widget in the latest version or has it been changed?  Thanks.

Comment: `ConsumerWidget` from `flutter_riverpod` and `HookWidget` from flutter_hooks, can share your code snippet ?

Comment: this is a snippet right from the riverpod documentation. It is used in the standard flutter counter app. 

class Count extends HookConsumerWidget {   @override   Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {     int count = ref.watch(counterProvider).state;     return Text('$count');   } }

Comment: can you provide the link

Comment: [https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading#useprovider-hooks_riverpod-only](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading#useprovider-hooks_riverpod-only)

Comment: i just found an issue there is outdated documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Check your riverpod version.
I had the same issue using the version 0.14.0+4 but the problem is solved using ^1.0.0-dev.5.